# Regex to truncate a string on nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, caching

I am trying to use nginx caching features, however we have and endpoint that uses latitude and longitude, so for that, to increase the cache hit ratio, we have to truncate lat and long.

I created a map to ignore last two latitude digits. The problem is the map isn't working, it always returns the original latitude (45.45452).

Consider $arg_latitude being 45.45452, the expected result is 45.45.

```
map $arg_latitude $rounded_latitude {
    default $arg_latitude;
    ~\d+\.\d\d $arg_latitude;
}
```

Any idea why isn't working?

Comment: Surely there is a math library you can use to round a float? [I can't reproduce the problem](https://regex101.com/r/hae0M4/1)

Comment: The regex is supposed to be working. Regarding the math library, I prefer not using any external libs.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your pattern with `"..."`?

Comment: Yep, I tried it too, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your `map` is always the original value of `$arg_latitude`, because that is the value that you have inserted in the right hand column.

You need to add a capture to your regular expression and use that as the new value.

For example:

```
map $arg_latitude $rounded_latitude {
    default                 $arg_latitude;
    ~^(?<rounded>\d+\.\d\d) $rounded;
}
```

Use of a named capture is recommended, as a numeric capture may not be in-scope at the point where `$rounded_latitude` is evaluated.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.